# Rails javascript_include_tag tags in liquid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, liquid

I'm trying to get `javascript_include_tag("jquery")` to work in a Liquid tag inside rails. My problem is that `javascript_include_tag("jquery")` returns `<script src="/javascript/jquery.js"></script>`. And not: `<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js"></script>`. Also in production the tag does not add the file fingerprint.

```
  class JqueryTag < ::Liquid::Tag
    # Include the stylesheet tag link helper
    include ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper


    def render(context)
      return javascript_include_tag("jquery")
    end

  end

  Liquid::Template.register_tag('jquery_tag', JqueryTag)
```

Answer (score 2):

Finaly found an answer.

Including `include ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper` was not enough.

Instead i needed to do this.

```
  class JqueryTag < ::Liquid::Tag

    def render(context)
      helpers.javascript_include_tag("jquery")
    end

    def helpers
      @helpers ||= ActionController::Base.helpers
    end

  end

  Liquid::Template.register_tag('jquery_tag', JqueryTag)
```